# How to combine 2 tables into one?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, merge

I have two tables (A) & (B), with almost the same information at different dates.

TABLE (A)

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+
|ID  | Date       | Status   | Amount|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
| A1 | 01/14/2011 | Received |15     |
| A2 | 01/18/2011 | Received |65     |
| T3 | 01/9/2011  | Received |85     |
| X7 | 02/16/2011 | Received |35     |
| A5 | 01/3/2011  | Received |10     |
+----+------------+----------+-------+
```

TABLE (B)

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+
|ID  | Date       | Status   | Amount|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
| A1 | 03/31/2012 | Approved |15     |
| A2 | 03/31/2012 | Denied   |65     |
| A3 | 03/31/2012 | Approved |85     |
| A7 | 03/31/2012 | Received |35     |
| A5 | 03/31/2012 | pending  |10     |
+----+------------+----------+-------+
```

I am trying to merge them in order to obtain a new table (result) like this:

TABLE (RESULT)

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+
|ID  | Date       | Status   | Amount|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
| A1 | 01/14/2011 | Received |15     |
| A1 | 03/31/2012 | Approved |15     |
| A2 | 01/18/2011 | Received |65     |
| A2 | 03/31/2012 | Denied   |65     |
| A5 | 01/3/2011  | Received |10     |
| A5 | 03/31/2012 | pending  |10     |
+----+------------+----------+-------+
```

I used this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
ORDER BY table1.id;
```

Here is the result:

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+------------+---------+
| ID | Date       | Status   | Amount| Date_1     | Status_1   | Amount_1|
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+------------+---------+
| A1 | 01/14/2011 | Received |15     |03/31/2012  | Approved   |15       |
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+------------+---------+
```

It's working fine but it's not what I am looking for. I don't want duplicate columns side by side. I was thinking about using INSERT INTO or UNION ALL but I am not sure.

Comment: What does "like this" mean? Please don't expect people to guess from an example, use words to say what an example is an example of.

Answer (score 1):

With UNION including from each table only rows with corresponding rows in the other table:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TableB
  WHERE ID = a.ID AND Amount = a.Amount AND Status <> a.Status
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB b
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TableA
  WHERE ID = b.ID AND Amount = b.Amount AND Status <> b.Status
)
ORDER BY ID;
```

I am not sure about the condition `Amount = x.Amount`. Maybe you want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple union all query to do the job:

```
select * from a where id in (select id from b)
union all
select * from b where id in (select id from a)
order by id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.id, x.status, x.amount, y.status, y.amount
from 
(
select 'A1' id, 'received' status, 15 amount from dual
union all
select 'A2' id, 'received' status, 65 amount from dual
) x,
 (
select 'A1' id, 'approved' status, 15 amount from dual
union all
select 'A2' id, 'denied' status, 65 amount from dual
) y
where x.id = y.id
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    --Get results from both tables
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
) t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t2.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the aim (which you haven't really described) is to report the rows from either table whose ID exists in both tables, then perhaps you want this:

```
select id, somedate, status, amount
from   ( select id, somedate, status, amount from table_a
         union all
         select id, somedate, status, amount from table_b )
where  id in
       ( select id from table_a
         intersect
         select id from table_b )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Status, Amount
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Date, Status, Amount
from table2
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I must have misunderstood the results you want. If there is a record in one table and not in the other you don't want it.